# AWS instance can't be accessed from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I set up kubernetes cluster and then I deployed it on AWS . It created one load balancer, one master and 4 minion nodes.

I can use kubectl proxy command to check whether it works locally and it turned out that yes. I am able to connect to a particular pod.

The problem is that I can't access it externally. I have IP which looks like this :

```
ab0154f2bcc5c11e6aff30a71ada8ce9-447509613.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I also modified security group, so each node has a following security group :

```
Ports   Protocol    Source  
80      tcp           0.0.0.0/0 
8080    tcp          0.0.0.0/0  
All     All   sg-4dbbce2b, sg-4ebbce28, sg-e6a4d180 
22      tcp         0.0.0.0/0
```

What might be wrong with this configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the service which created the ELB have `endpoints`. Do a `kubectl describe svc <serviceName>` and check the `endpoints` section. If not then you need to match up the selectors better. If you do see them then I would try hitting the nodeport from one of the machines to verify it works. A simple `curl` should work. If that works then I would look deeper into the AWS security.